# Citizenship limitations for E2 visa

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, immigration, usa

The company I currently work for is British and I'm resident in the UK but I have an Italian passport. My company wants to bring me to their office in the US with an [E2 visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-2_visa) but they believe that they can't do so because I'm not British.

Italy though is included in the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-2_visa#cite_note-1) of [Treaty Countries](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/fees/treaty.html), does it matter that the company is British? Is that a real blocker?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Got an (disappointing) answer after some research..

`Treaty visas are authorized on the basis of treaties of commerce and navigation between the United States and certain countries [..]. Please note that the Enterprise must be majority-owned, as well as developed and directed by nationals of the Treaty Country (“Treaty Country Nationals”), and individual employees must have the same nationality as the Enterprise to qualify.`
[Source](https://de.usembassy.gov/visas/e-1e-2-treaty-traderinvestor-visa/)

**UPDATE:**
~This now confuses me:~
`Nationality: The investor (either a real or corporate person) must be a national of a treaty country and the entity must hold that same nationality. Under the law, a U.S. entity may qualify as an E-2 enterprise if it is owned by 50% or more by treaty nationals.` [Source](http://www.gandsinvestors.com/united-states/e-2-nonimmigrant-investor-visa)

~So since most of the other employees are British I may qualify?~ (~ = striketrhough)

Comment: Employees must have the same nationality as the investor to qualify for the E-2 visa.  As an Italian national, you could get one only if you were employed by an Italian investor.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Any useful info/links about B visa limitations regarding the work location? I'm reading about L1b and that may fit too..
Many thanks